# Max height of object launched from simple see-saw catapult?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

I have been interested in the following question and I just wanted to present my solution to see if it makes sense. Consider a heavy object of mass $M_o$ which is being dropped from a height $H_o$ into a cup of mass $M_c$ attached to the end of a (thin) plank of mass $M_p$ and length $L$. The other end of the plank contains a marshmallow of mass $M_m \ll M_o$ and the center point of the plank is angled on top of an inclined plane (with sufficient friction to prevent from sliding) at a height $H_p$ as depicted below

[image]

When $M_o$ drops into the cup with speed $v_o = \sqrt{2 g (H_o-2 H_p)}$ just before collision, it will collide an an angle $\theta$ to the normal given by $\sin(\theta) = 2 H_p/L$. From angular momentum conservation, I can write

\begin{equation}
M_o v_o (L/2) \cos(\theta) = I \omega_1 
\end{equation}

for the angular speed $\omega_1$ just after the collision with rotational inertia $I = (1/12) M_p L^2 + (M_o + M_m + M_c)(L/2)^2$. Using conservation of energy, I can then solve for the angular speed $\omega_2$ just before the plank hits the ground using

\begin{equation}
(M_o + M_c)g(2 H_p) + \frac{1}{2} I \omega_1^2 = M_m g (2 H_p) + \frac{1}{2} I \omega_2^2
\end{equation}

After this, the system looks like the following (the marshmallow has parabolic motion):

[image]

From here, I could assume the marshmallow will have a speed equal to the left end of the rotating plank $v_p = (L/2) \omega_2$. However, in actually conducting this experiment, I find this under-predicts the max height (gives around 34cm) and doesn't account for the fact that the plank will actually lift off the inclined plane and start rotating about its right end. If we assume that the rod will suddenly start rotating around its right end with new angular speed $\omega_3$ given by (assuming energy conservation)

\begin{equation}
 \omega_3 = \omega_2 \sqrt{I/I'}
\end{equation}

where $I' = \frac{1}{3} M_p L^2 + M_m L^2$ is the new rotational inertia. This gives a predicted height of around 165cm using $v_p = L \omega_3$ which is better, but I feel like this energy conservation step is not justified.

To predict the maximum height, I am using

\begin{equation}
H_m = \frac{(v_p \cos(\theta))^2}{2 g} + 2 H_p
\end{equation}
which assumes the speed of the left end of the plank is the same as the marshmallow at lift off.

This experiment was conducted in a middle school classroom as a qualitative demonstration of energy conversion from potential to kinetic energy, but predicting the height was not expected, but is what I want to do. For comparison, here are some parameters used in this experiment:
$M_m = 5.9$ g, $M_c = 9.2$ g, $M_p = 87.7 g$, $M_o = 143.2$ g, $H_p = 2.0$ cm, $H_o = 52$ cm, $L = 61.5$ cm

My predictions: **38 cm** (Method 1) and **165 cm** (Method 2)

Typical Heights Seen in Experiment: Around **200cm**.

In summary, I have a few questions:

1. How do we treat the interaction of the plank with the floor? Does this depend on the material and floor properties?
2. Why is it possible for the height to be larger than 165cm?
3. Is there a way I can numerically model this process using some sort of rigid body simulation?

I know I have made a few assumptions which are not strictly true. First, the plank isn't exactly centered with respect to the inclined plane, it is shifted slightly to the left by around 1-2cm. Second, I did not account for the thickness of the plank. Third, nothing is anchored to the floor or each other. Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: One note, you say $M_c \sim M_m$ however it's near 50% more massive than $M_m$, I wouldn't call this approximately equal to, though you haven't used that information anywhere anyways. Also will not the marshmallow execute parabolic motion? In that sense energy needs to be split between horizontal and vertical velocities.

Comment: @Triatticus Thanks for your comment, I've modified my post.

Comment: The initial velocity of the little ball is not vertical. Why would it be?